# Discord - accept_invite() Error 403

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to see if i could get a bot to auto-join my server but when i wrote the code and then ran it i got this exception:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\datpe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 275, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\datpe\Desktop\Python Files\discord.py-async\examples\basic_bot.py", line 7, in on_ready
    await client.accept_invite('https://discord.gg/AFBEwNE')
  File "C:\Users\datpe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2237, in accept_invite
    yield from self.http.accept_invite(invite_id)
  File "C:\Users\datpe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 133, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Bots cannot use this endpoint
```

As you can see, my request got Forbidden because Bots cannot use this endpoint

Could someone give me some insight into this?

Also here is my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.accept_invite('https://discord.gg/AFBEwNE')

client.run('Bot Token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots cannot accept invites full stop. You must use the authorisation link, which for bots created after some time in march, uses the bot's ID, and for those before use the application ID from the application web page.

```
https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<BOTS_ID_HERE>&scope=bot
```

Comment: Thought so, that sucks.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, for security reasons bots can only be authorized by members with the "Manage Server" permission.

You can fetch the link in the discord developers page under the 0Auth2. Make sure to tick all the permissions you want the bot to have and select the bot scope, then copy the 2auth0 link and share it to whom needs it.